# string (file1.txt) search from file2.txt

Tags: python, string, search

`file1.txt` contains usernames, i.e.

```
tony  
peter  
john  
...
```

`file2.txt` contains user details, just one line for each user details, i.e.

```
alice 20160102 1101 abc  
john 20120212 1110 zjc9  
mary 20140405 0100 few3  
peter 20140405 0001 io90  
tango 19090114 0011 n4-8  
tony 20150405 1001 ewdf  
zoe 20000211 0111 jn09  
...
```

I want to get a shortlist of user details from `file2.txt` by `file1.txt` user provided, i.e.

```
john 20120212 1110 zjc9  
peter 20140405 0001 io90  
tony 20150405 1001 ewdf
```

How to use python to do this?

Comment: If you start each line with four space it gets rendered in code format - or you can use the {} button to format highlighted code in the markdown editor.

Comment: SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service. Please learn [ask].

Comment: please read about [python files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) and [strings](http://www.learnpython.org/en/Basic_String_Operations). if you get some error while programming, then ask question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.split(' ')`, assuming that there will always be a space between the name and the other information in the `file2.txt`

Here's an example:

```
UserList = []

with open("file1.txt","r") as fuser:
        UserLine = fuser.readline()
        while UserLine!='':
            UserList.append(UserLine.split("\n")[0])    # Separate the user name from the new line command in the text file.
            UserLine = fuser.readline() 

InfoUserList = []   
InfoList = []

with open("file2.txt","r") as finfo:
        InfoLine = finfo.readline()
        while InfoLine!='':
            InfoList.append(InfoLine)
            line1 = InfoLine.split(' ')
            InfoUserList.append(line1[0])   # Take just the user name to compare it later
            InfoLine = finfo.readline()

for user in UserList:
    for i in range(len(InfoUserList)):
        if user == InfoUserList[i]:
            print InfoList[i]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_csv('df1.txt', header=None)
df2 = pd.read_csv('df2.txt', header=None)
df1[0] = df1[0].str.strip() # remove the 2 whitespace followed by the feild
df2 = df2[0].str[0:-2].str.split(' ').apply(pd.Series) # split the word and remove whitespace
df = df1.merge(df2)

Out[26]: 
       0         1     2     3
0   tony  20150405  1001  ewdf
1  peter  20140405  0001  io90
2   john  20120212  1110  zjc9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

file1 = pd.read_csv('file1.txt', sep =' ', header=None)
file2 = pd.read_csv('file2.txt', sep=' ', header=None)

shortlist = file2.loc[file2[0].isin(file1.values.T[0])]
```

it will give you the following result:

```
       0         1     2     3
1   john  20120212  1110  zjc9
3  peter  20140405     1  io90
5   tony  20150405  1001  ewdf
```

The above is a `DataFrame` to convert it back to an array just use `shortlist.values`